# How to use JSR223 timer in JMeter

Tags: groovy, timer, jmeter

I want to use JSR223 timer in JMeter and not manage to execute delay,

If I want to create thread delay of 30 seconds what should I write inside the script section ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of creating a delay via script-based timer is using [`return` keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html), the value should have [Long data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) and the delay is in milliseconds.

So creating a 30-seconds delay would be something like:

```
return 30000
```

More information: [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

Answer (score 1):

Thread delay is created by calling sleep method which wait by given parameter in milliseconds, in your case:

```
sleep(30000);
```