# Trouble creating a Timer in jMeter/Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, stress-testing

i have timestamp values in a csv file and i'm loading the file in a ThreadgGoup in jMeter.
I'm using a JSR223 script to calculate the delay time between each thread but i'm having trouble doing that.

I want to launch my threads based no real life data, that's why i'm using the timestamps from a csv log file. but i don't know how to configure the equation for this.
I'm reading the timestamp from the csv in my script and i know that the wait time should equal the current timestamp value - previous thread timestamp value but how can i implement this?

```
def long wait=0;

// this returns the currents threads timestamp value from the csv
def long ts = Double.valueOf(vars.get("timestamp")).longValue();

wait = ts - {previous timestamp in csv}

return wait;
```

I'm using groovy to write the scripts and in my threadgroup i have the httpRequest and in it the JSR223 Timer. Any thoughts?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496012/how-to-use-jsr223-timer-in-jmeter

Comment: @user7294900 i already checked that post. that guy is using a constant timer. I don't want that. I'm trying to create a timer that will change its value for each thread based on the timestamps it reads in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of return the wait you should pass it to sleep method:

```
 sleep(wait);
```

For reading CSV see [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48008527/how-to-read-the-csv-file-data-one-by-one-and-put-into-variable-using-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

You code should be:

```
 // this returns the currents threads timestamp value from the csv
 long ts = vars["timestamp"].toLong();
 long wait = ts - {previous timestamp in csv}
 return wait;
```

What I don't understand is where this value comes from:

> {previous timestamp in csv}

Finally you need to understand how timer work:

- [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
- [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

So if you really want to apply it between sampler, ensure you put your timer as a child of [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action):

[image: JSR223 Timer as child of Flow Control Action]

Answer (score 0):

Get used to look into *jmeter.log* file - normally it should contain the reason of your Groovy (or JMeter) test misbehaviour or failure. The [Log Viewer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) window can be opened by clicking on a yellow triangle in the upper right corner of JMeter GUI

Amend your code to look like:

```
if (vars.get('previousTimestamp') != null) {
    long ts = vars.get('timestamp') as Long
    long wait = ts - (vars.get('previousTimestamp') as Long)
    return wait
} else {
    vars.put('previousTimestamp', vars.get('timestamp') as String)
    //return 1000
}
```

The logic is:

1. If `previousTimestamp` variable is defined - "sleep" for delta time between the previous and the current timestamps
2. If `previousTimestamp` variable is not defined - store current `timestamp` variable as `previousTimestamp` and don't sleep. You can uncomment `return 1000` line to provide a "default" sleep of 1 second

Just in case check out [Mathematical Functions and Converting Data Types in Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mathematical-functions-and-converting-data-types-in-groovy) guide, it should give you more insight on what you're trying to implement.